# How to solve "Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)': Shapes (unknown member): invalid request. The specified data type i unavailable"

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to automate a report from Excel to Powerpoint. I get the same error message. Sometimes the script works, some don't. I read something about "Panes" in another thread, but I didn't understand what to do with the info. The string causing the error is:

---

> activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteBitmap).Select

---

I'm not very familiar with programming, so please take that in consideration. Thank you!

Right now i just continue the exports, and compensates with manual work for the slides that doesn't work.

```
    'SLIDE HISTORICALS Germany _____________________________________________________________
    'Add a new slide where we will paste the chart
        newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

            Sheets("Historicals Output").Activate

    'Copy the chart and paste it into the PowerPoint as a Metafile Picture
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Historicals Output").Range("A86:S118").Select
        Selection.Copy
```

'''activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteBitmap).Select'''

```
    'Set the title of the slide the same as the title of the chart
       ' activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text

    'Adjust the positioning of the Chart on Powerpoint Slide
       ' newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 15
       newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 70

        ' create textbox
        Sheets("Text").Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Text").Range("b12:z12").Select
        Selection.Copy''' activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteBitmap).Select '''
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 0
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0
```

I would be so thankful to make this run smooth.

Comment: Is the host application Excel or PowerPoint?

Comment: The host program is excel. I want to export a report from excel to powerpoint. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See if this is the case.

PowerPoint usually needs some time after pasting something onto the slide.

Especially an OLE object like Excel table takes a while.

Try adding following code sniffet.

```
...
Selection.Copy
activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteBitmap)

'Let's give some break time
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until activeSlide.Shapes.Count > 0  ' use '0' if pasted on a new slide

'Select the last shape pasted
activeSlide.Shapes(activeSlide.Shapes.Count).Select
...
```